# how can i call two functions with the third function?

Tags: python

How can I call two functions with the third function?

I want to combine count_authors code and authors_counts into one simple function in report_author_counts and return the right answer showed below

```
   def count_authors(file_name):
         invert = {}
         for k, v in load_library(file_name).items():
            invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1
         return invert


    def authors_counts(counts, file_name):
        total_books = 0
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            for name, count in counts.items():
                f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count))
                total_books += int(count)
            f.write('TOTAL BOOKS: ' + str(total_books))



    def report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
        counts = count_authors(lib_fpath)
        authors_counts(counts, rep_filepath)
```

my code after trying to add them ..invert is not reachable in the return  i want to remove file_name from the function parameter because the automatic evaluation expect two parameters (lib_fpath, rep_filepath)

```
def report_author_counts(file_name, lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
    invert={}
    counts = {}
    for k, v in load_library(file_name).items():
       invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1

    total_books = 0
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for name, count in counts.items():
            f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count))
            total_books += int(count)
        f.write('TOTAL BOOKS: ' + str(total_books))

        counts = invert(lib_fpath)
    return (counts, rep_filepath)
```

expected output

```
Clarke, Arthur C.: 2
Herbert, Frank: 2
Capek, Karel: 1
Asimov, Isaac: 3
TOTAL BOOKS: 8
```

dictionary

```
Foundation|Asimov, Isaac
Foundation and Empire|Asimov, Isaac
Second Foundation|Asimov, Isaac
Dune|Herbert, Frank
Children of Dune|Herbert, Frank
RUR|Capek, Karel
2001: A Space Odyssey|Clarke, Arthur C.
2010: Odyssey Two|Clarke, Arthur C.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would not advice you to combine these functions unless you are operating in some high-performance environment. The first version is much clearer than the second. When that is said I think you just have to replace `file_name` with `lib_fpath` in the code that relates to `count_authors`, and with `rep_filepath` in the code that relates to `authors_counts`, replace `counts` with `invert`. Like this:

```
def report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
    invert = {}
    total_books = 0
    for k, v in load_library(lib_fpath).items():
        invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1

    with open(rep_filepath, 'w') as f:
        for name, count in invert.items():
            f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count))
            total_books += int(count)
        f.write('TOTAL BOOKS: ' + str(total_books))
```

Comment: and how can i return them?

Comment: @loco `return invert` at the bottom will return the dictionary. `return (invert, total_books)` will return the number of books as well. I'm unsure what you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

your error is in **count_authors** you are using the value instead of the key:
If I understand you correctly you function should be like this:

```
def count_authors(file_name):
    invert = load_library(file_name)
    for k, v in invert.items():
        if not invert.get(k, False):
            invert[k] = 0
        return invert
```